# What is the probability that a man appearing near the tower will stay in the dark for at least 5 seconds?

Tags: probability

> A searchlight on top of the watch-tower makes 3 revolutions per
>   minute. What is the probability that a man appearing near the tower
>   will stay in the dark for at least 5 seconds?

The problem seems fuzzy to  me because, it is impossible to say that segment area  of the light which illuminates  the man. But it is quite clear that the light passes the man in every 20 secs from the question. The questions says that the man will get illuminated after 20 sec but  not how many secs it remains.

Can you clarify pleasE?

Answer (score 1):

To easier visualize the problem, we can say the searchlight is traveling around the unit circle clockwise at $18$ degrees per second. Let's say the man approaches the tower at $\theta=0$. Then to remain hidden for at least $5$ seconds, the searchlight must not be in the area $0\le\theta\le18\times5=90$. Therefore the probability is just $1-1/4=3/4$.

Alternatively, you could quite easily reason informally that the probability is just $1-5\text{ seconds}/20\text{ seconds}=3/4$.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe Ant confused himself. If the spotlight goes 3 revolution in 60 seconds, then it goes 1 revolution in 20 seconds and 1/4 revolutions in 5 seconds.

Now, let us fix the position of the man. If the light is to catch him before 5 seconds it must be 1/4 of a revolution (or less) behind him. Thus, the probability it catches him is 1/4 and the probability that he is not seen for more than 5 seconds is 3/4.

Comment: Tell me if you see why this must be so @ant11

Answer (score 0):

Let's formulate what @122520253025 said more mathematically.

Let's consider $t=0$ the moment when the light leaves the point M, which will be the point where the man arrives.
Now, let's consider $x$ the moment when the man arrives. If $ mod(x,20) < 15$, then the man will stay in the dark for 5 seconds at least. Since we can model this problem using a uniformly distributed law, then we are just looking to find $\mathbb P(mod(x,20)<15)$, knowing that $\mathbb P(mod(x,20)<20)=1$.
Finally, using the uniformly distributed law, we find out that $$\mathbb P(mod(x,20)<15)=\frac{3}{4}$$